# Struct with pointer to a function

Tags: c, function, struct, pointers

In a C struct I have defined a function pointer as follows:

```
typedef struct _sequence_t
{
  const int seq[3];
  typedef void (* callbackPtr)();
} sequence_t;
```

I want to initialize a var of that type globally with:

```
sequence_t sequences[] = {
  { { 0, 1, 2 }, toggleArmament },
};
```

And I keep getting error telling me that there are too many initializers. How to work it out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`typedef` is used to declare an alias to a type. Since you have an actual member here, remove the inner `typedef`.

```
typedef struct _sequence_t
{
  const int seq[3];
  void (* callbackPtr)();
} sequence_t;
```