# How to use function pointers in a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

It's pretty simple what I'm trying to do, and I'm merely having trouble figuring out the right syntax.

I want my struct to look like this:

```
struct myStruct
{
   functionPointer myPointer;
}
```

Then I have another function somewhere else that passes a function to a function and returns an instance of my struct.  Here's what it does:

```
struct myStruct myFunction(int (*foo) (void *))
{
   myStruct c;
   c.myPointer = foo;
   return c;
}
```

How can I make this actually work?  What's the correct syntax for:

1. Declaring a function pointer in my struct (obviously `functionPointer myPointer;` is incorrect)
2. Assigning a function's address to that function pointer (pretty sure `c.myPointer = foo` is incorrect)?

Comment: If you return a myStruct *, you should allocate (eg, use malloc) and return the malloced value.  If you return a myStruct, you should declare your function as such.  (Right now, you declare that the function returns a pointer, but you attempt to return a struct.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function Pointer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278841/). See also [Function pointer as a member of a C struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350376/), [Struct with pointer to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939003/), [typedef is your friend](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028634/90527).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really no different to any other instance of a function pointer:

```
struct myStruct
{
   int (*myPointer)(void *);
};
```

Although often one would use a `typedef` to tidy this up a little.

Answer (score 0):

More or less:

```
struct myStruct
{
    struct myStruct (*myPointer)(int (*foo)(void *));
};
typedef struct myStruct myStruct;
```

The `c.myPointer` should be fine, but you need to return a copy of the structure, not a pointer to the now vanished local variable `c`.

```
struct myStruct
{
    struct myStruct (*myPointer)(int (*foo)(void *));
};
typedef struct myStruct myStruct;

struct myStruct myFunction(int (*foo) (void *))
{
    myStruct c;
    c.myPointer = foo;
    return c;
}
```

This compiles but the compiler (reasonably) complains that `foo` is not really the correct type.  So, the issue is - what is the correct type for the function pointer in the structure?  And that depends on what you want it to do.

Comment: Your struct contains a pointer to a function returning your struct taking a pointer to another function returning an int taking a pointer to void? My head hurts.